# Importing React component from dependency in linked local folder in Vite breaks in runtime

Tags: reactjs, npm, vite

I have a problem with React setup with linked dependencies (in monorepo). If I import a component from linked dependency, it works in vite dev server, but breaks in runtime if bundled for prod. My problem emerged in complex codebase, but I managed to create simplified reproducible example.

I have following directory structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   ├── tsconfig.node.json
│   ├── vite.config.ts
│   └── yarn.lock
├── common
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── MyButton.tsx
│   └── yarn.lock
├── compose.yml
└── Dockerfile
```

Where `app` directory is just the boilerplate created via:

```bash
yarn create vite app --template react-swc-ts
```

And `common` directory contains my simple component with state (MyButton.tsx):

```
import { useState } from "react";

export function MyButton() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("click me");

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setText("different")}>{text}</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

And package.json contents are as follows:

```json
{
  "name": "my-modules",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.21"
  }
}
```

What I do:

Add my modules folder to `app/package.json` as a linked dependency:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "my-modules": "link:../common"
  },
```

Import and use `<MyButton/>` in `app/src/App.tsx`

```
import { MyButton } from 'my-modules/MyButton'

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
      ...some other code from vite template...
      <MyButton />
    </>
  )
}
```

Now if I do:

```
cd app
yarn dev
```

Everything works correctly, I can see my button.

But when I bundle for production `yarn build` (i.e. vite build) and serve the bundle via nginx, it shows empty page because of JS error. Error message it fails with comes from inside React (inside useState function):

```
TypeError: ce.current is null
    useState http://localhost:6789/assets/index-2abe1d2d.js:48
    zp http://localhost:6789/assets/index-2abe1d2d.js:56
    ...
```

JSX/TSX itself is not an issue. If I change `common/MyButton.tsx` to:

```
export function MyButton() {

  return (
    <>
      <button>Plain button</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

It works normally in both cases.

Given this information, I assume it has to do with how Vite resolves and bundles dependencies like React in production. Both app and `common` components list react as their dependencies, so maybe Vite does not deduplicate it correctly.

But how to fix this? And what is the reason it works in dev server and not in prod?

Thanks in advance.